# JBoss AS 7 and MySQL - Can't start server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, datasource

I've followed [this](https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/) tutorial to set up MySQL with JBoss AS 7. Unfortunately the server hangs on the message:

```
INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
```

And nothing happens.

What could cause this problem?

Full log:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /Applications/JBoss

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

11:42:35,759 INFORMATION [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:42:36,067 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:42:36,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
11:42:37,280 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
11:42:37,294 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
11:42:37,292 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:42:37,305 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
11:42:37,379 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
11:42:37,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
11:42:37,454 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:42:37,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:42:37,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
11:42:37,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
11:42:37,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
11:42:37,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:42:37,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
11:42:37,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
11:42:37,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:42:37,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:42:37,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
11:42:37,565 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]): org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl$ContextServiceBuilder.install(OperationContextImpl.java:955) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.startDriverServices(JdbcDriverAdd.java:164) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.performRuntime(JdbcDriverAdd.java:128) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:50) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceEnable$1.execute(DataSourceEnable.java:91) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceEnable$1.execute(DataSourceEnable.java:91) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:311) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]

11:42:38,026 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
11:42:38,116 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
```

This is the corresponding content of my standalone.xml:

```html
<datasources>
    <datasource
            jndi-name="java:/database" pool-name="mySQLPool"
            enabled="true" jta="true"
            use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
        </connection-url>
        <driver>
            mysql
        </driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>
                username
            </user-name>
            <password>
       password
            </password>
        </security>
        <statement>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                100
            </prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements/>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
        <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>
                org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
            </xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

Whereas database, username and password are set correctly.

Comment: Can you paste your standalone.xml?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is 2 driver definitions in META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver.
Also this problem may be cause by MySQL Driver version.
1)Change your MySQL Driver version.(May be MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1.30 and up has this issues,  you should change lower version)

 **OR** 
 
2)Add eg: line to the "drivers" section in the subsystem "datasources" in **standalone.xml**

eg:

```
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding the driver-class tag to my standalone.xml solved the problem, while keeping the newest driver. I wonder why all the tutorials don't contain that part. Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: I would like to clarify that the "driver-class" tag, goes inner the MySql "driver" class.

Comment: Thank, helped alot, this should be included and updated on their tutorials.

Comment: Your driver tag should look like this: 
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
 <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but could resolve by downgrading the MySQL driver version to mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar

Here is the module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Works well with JBoss AS 7.1.1

:Vinod.